# Не работает flask run в терминале дериктории

Tags: python

Делал код по методичке 1. создал текстовый файл заполнил 2. заполнил 3 строки 3. pip3 install -r req.txt 4. далее высветилась проблема
и не мог использовать в терминале директории flask run (изначально думал что не так что-то с импортом но объяснили что все ок) [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А в методичке тоже после requests новая строка?

Comment: Почему вы решили, что не работает? На показанном вами скриншоте нет никаких ошибок, только предупреждения о неиспользуемых переменных

Comment: я просто не понимаю почему flask run не работает и подумал что может изза этого

Comment: «не мог использовать в терминале» — что это означает? Кто и как помешал вам пользоваться терминалом?

Comment: открыл терминал и ввел flask run, команда не работала

Comment: Что означает «команда не работала», что произошло вместо работы?

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка говорит о том что ты импортировал модуль но не используешь его, ошибка не критичная